# How to create top and bottom corner radius different on WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I need to set a corner radius to 6 on top of WKInterfaceGroup and set to 0 on bottom.
Is there a tips or anything ?

Thanks

Example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvA6X.jpg

Comment: let radius be 0 and set a image to group having a curve form top

Answer (score 1):

Since many elements (images e. g.) can't be given a border radius in watchOS, you should use groups with images as their only element. In order to achieve two different border sizes, try using two groups with two different border sizes which overlap themselves, so that one side of the border isn't visible because it's overlapped by the other group.